# Garbage in array after calling function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, matrix, matrix-multiplication

The problem occurs in `foo()` (in the commented lines), and is that `foo2()` should return the result of a matrix multiplication repeated process in it's first parameter. It is working in the first case and failing right after.

`B` and `B_tmp` arrays should have the same values at the end of `foo()` and that's not happening

`T` is 1x6 matrix, `A` is 6x3 matrix, `B` is 200x3 matrix

`foo3()` multiplies TxA and store the result (1x3 matrix) at the end of `B`

What `foo2()` does at the beginning with B_t1_t2 is not relevant, it just prepares the 1x6 matrix, changing the order in some way

I must try to solve this without changing any function declaration
I'm new to c++ and have been searching for too long now, I'm desperated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

double fRand(const double & min, const double & max) {
    thread_local std::mt19937 generator(std::random_device{}());
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(min, max);
    return distribution(generator);
}

int iRand(const int & min, const int & max) {
    thread_local std::mt19937 generator(std::random_device{}());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(min, max);
    return distribution(generator);
} 

void foo3(double T[6], double A[18], double *B)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        double r = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            r += T[j] * A[i*3+j];
        }
        *B = r; B++;
    }
}

void foo2(double *B, double *A, int from, int to)
{
    for (int i=from; i < to; i++) {         //This is not relevant but I leave it just in case
        double B_t1_t2[6];
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
            B_t1_t2[x] = B[(i-1)*3 + x];
        for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
            B_t1_t2[x+3] = B[(i-2)*3 + x];

        foo3(B_t1_t2, A, &B[i*3]);
    }
}


void foo(double *A, double *B)
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++)
        A[i] = fRand(1, 2);

    foo2(B, A, 2, 200);
    cout << "\nB" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 600; i++)
        cout << B[i] << " "; // HERE IS WORKING, B DOES NOT CONTAIN GARBAGE
    cout << endl;

    double B_tmp[600];
    foo2(B_tmp, A, 2, 200);
    cout << "\nB_tmp" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 600; i++)
        cout << B_tmp[i] << " "; // WHY NOT WORKING HERE?
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    double A[18], B[600];

    for(int i = 0; i<6; i++)
        B[i] = 1;

    foo(A, B);
}
```

Why the second `cout` in `foo()` is showing garbage?
Also, if declarations must change, what would be the best way?

Im trying to use stack memory as much as I can.

Comment: mark function & vars as code to differ from free text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before calling `foo(A, B);` first 6 elements of B array were filled (all are set to 1). In `foo` function you call `foo2` function twice. In first call you pass `B` array into `foo2` function, and it works because `B` is filled. In second call of `foo2` in `foo` you pass `B_tmp` array but all items of this array have garbage value, you didn't initialize them. So do

```
double B_tmp[600];
for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    B_tmp[i] = 1;
foo2(B_tmp, A, 2, 200);
```